# Error in VS 2017 for C language

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set up a project in visual studios for C but every time i do, i first get this error message

```
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
```

then when i fix it by going into the "Properties->Precompiled header" i get this message

```
error LNK2005: _main already defined in clang.obj
```

. This has been going on for days now and i watched a bunch of videos and read a bunch of articles on this and I can't seem to find a fix. I just want to run my C program and have it execute without dealing with errors like those above. Here is what i do to set it up,

1. Create new project -> Select "Windows console application" -> change the "Location" to a file directory on my desktop -> then go to "Project" and "Add new item" -> i name that item "name.c" and when I am done, I insert my code and run it then i receive the same errors. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you choose `Windows console application` template, VS 2017 already generated a file which has a `int main()` function defined in it.

Then you added another file `name.c` which also has a `main()` function. Thus you got that error.

Comment: so should i use the file they create with the ".cpp" extension or?

Comment: in your case, I would suggest that.

Comment: i still get the same errors when i run it in the cpp file

Comment: after you click "windows console application", don't add any of your stuff, build it first.

Comment: It that build is fine, then if the build failed after you add your own code, you need to check your code. without details , we cannot help you.

Comment: Wow ok now i see, so when i click "file" just click WCA and thats it. Then hit build "WCA" then put code and run. Works!! Thank you very much. But why do people create a project if they can just do it this way?

Comment: oh and if i send this to my teacher, will she be able to open it and run it?

Comment: you can send the whole folder to her.